# Applying a partial gaussian like blur to a background image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, png

I have and image which gets stretched to its full background, regardless of the monitor size.

What i need to do is apply cross-browser blur above this image on only a portion of the left hand side.

So it gives the appearance of a blur on the image. If i apply it to the image then when the screen resolution changes size so does the size of the blur.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: In CSS or on server side in the image? I assume the former?

Comment: Css would be great, although at this stage i would except anything.  By creating the blur (say 250px wide) on the left part of any background image it allows me to place a menu above it. Thats the idea.

Comment: I see... If it needs to be resizable, CSS will be your only option then. There is definitely no *one* cross-browser way to do it but I would surprise if CSS3 wouldn't have something to offer in that department.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this http://css-tricks.com/blurry-background-effect/

Comment: Looks like the only way to do this then is loading two images.

Comment: This is still a bummer because im applying it to this effect:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something like that. Especially not if cross browser also means IE6.

What you could do, however, is create a blurred and not blurred version of the image and show the blurred version only where you want it (cropped). If you know what I mean... :)

Comment: Not bothered by ie6, just ie7,8 and the others

Comment: @Jongsma @Andy funnily enough, IE in this case has a function to do it since 5.5, while FF3.6, Opera, and Chrome have not - not to my knowledge at least :)

Comment: mmm i see what you mean, that ordinarily wouldnt be a bad idea but again because the image is being stretched on the background the image above would mirror it.  It would look odd.  but nice idea!  thanks for the input.

Comment: i noticed those blur filters before, but its not cross browser...bit of a teaser this one.  For once it looks like IE may come out trumps...surely not? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely position a div that has a 50% width and a 100% height. Then made the background of the div about a 50% transparent white background. This might do the trick.

Comment: It's not real blurring though.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory glance tells me there is no CSS3 thingy for this. Surely this can't be true? Anybody?

For Internet Explorer, there is the proprietary [blur filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532979%28VS.85%29.aspx). Example from the MSDN site:

```
<DIV STYLE="width:100%; filter:
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.MotionBlur(strength=13, direction=310)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=2)
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Wheel(duration=3);">
Blurry text with smudge of gray.</div>
```